# An error while following official solr tutorial

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I'm following [this solr tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/doc-files/tutorial.html).

I successfully followed the steps up to the "updating data" part. At this part of the tutorial, I'm suggested to look at the statistics page at the link:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/stats.jsp
```

When I click this link I get this in the browser:

> HTTP ERROR 500 Problem accessing /solr/admin/stats.jsp. Reason: JSP
>   support not configured Powered by Jetty://

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Are you deploying Solr to an existing Jetty instance or using the one provided with Solr?

Comment: Well, I don't start a Jetty instance by  myself. I just started solr with command "$java -jar start.jar". Does solr itself starts a Jetty instance? If yes, how does it starts Jetty? If no, how can I start a jetty instance by myself? I used jetty with intellij idea, but have not worked with it at terminal, yet.

Comment: ok, then you are using the one bundled with Solr. Are you actually using a JDK? (not a JRE)

Comment: jpountz thanks for your answer. I solved the problem. The version of the tutorial is old and the given link is moved to another link. I just find the new link.

Comment: @ankakusu I'm having the same issue. Please answer to your own question and share the link you found working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my installation of solr 4.1 multi-core the following link worked: /solr//admin/mbeans?stats=true

Comment: Not able to get `/solr//admin/mbeans?stats=true` work too. I am trying to access the "stats page", any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind, got it here: `/solr/#/my_core_name/plugins/cache?entry=documentCache,queryResultCache`